# Copiar foto existente em link da web e colar especial como bitmap em célula do Excel via VBA

Tags: bitmap, excel-vba

Estou tentando colar imagem (em miniatura) vinculada a um link conforme abaixo:

Ex. A página WEB principal é: 
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071007/?ref_=nv_sr_7

A partir dessa página principal, pretendo copiar e colar como bitmap no Excel a imagem constante do link: www.imdb.com/name/nm0001271/?ref_=tt_cl_i1.

Veja o código VBA que tentei, mas não funciona:

```
Sub obter_imagem()

Dim v As Variant

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
.Visible = True
.Navigate "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071007/?ref_=nv_sr_7"
esperar = Now + TimeValue("0:00:30")
Do Until (.Busy = False And .ReadyState = 4) Or esperar < Now: DoEvents: Loop

x = 0
Do Until x >= 500
    Set foto = ie.Document.getelementsbytagname("A")(x)
    If foto Like "*cl_i1" Then
        foto.Select
        .Selection.Copy
        Sheets("FIGURAS").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Bitmap", link:=False, _      DisplayAsIcon:=False
        Exit Do
    End If
    x = x + 1
Loop

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Testei manualmente o link em que seu código navega, mas ele retorna uma página em branco (apenas com o cabeçalho, sem foto alguma). Talvez o problema seja o seu link.
Copie e cole ele no seu navegador para você ver.
Caso você queira expandir seu conhecimento, é mais rápido, eficiente e confiável obter dados através de uma requisição HTTP.
Neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933207/get-picture-as-http-get-response-and-insert-to-spreadsheet-without-saving-the-pi) um rapaz fez um código exatamente para obter uma imagem de uma página web usando uma requisição HTTP.
Já fiz várias rot